# More on $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(4n)!}{\Gamma\left(\frac23+n\right)\,\Gamma\left(\frac43+n\right)\,n!^2\,(-256)^n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, closed-form, hypergeometric-function

Let,
$$\alpha=2\sqrt[3]{1+\sqrt2}-\frac2{\sqrt[3]{1+\sqrt2}}$$
In [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/402432/4781), it was asked if,
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(4\,n)!}{\Gamma\left(\frac23+n\right)\,\Gamma\left(\frac43+n\right)\,n!^2\,(-256)^n}=\frac{\sqrt3}{2\,\pi}\left(2\sqrt{\frac8{\sqrt\alpha}-\alpha}-2\sqrt\alpha-3\right)$$
I was curious about this result, and a little experimentation showed that,
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(4\,n)!}{\Gamma\left(\frac23+n\right)\,\Gamma\left(\color{blue}{\frac13}+n\right)\,n!^2\,(-256)^n}=\frac{\sqrt3}{2\,\pi}\small\left(\frac16\sqrt{\frac{16}{\sqrt{2\alpha+8}}-\frac{\alpha-8}{2}}+\frac{1}{12}\sqrt{2\alpha+8}-1\right)$$
More generally, defining,
$$x=\frac{3}{4}+\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt3}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(4\,n)!}{\Gamma\left(\frac23+n\right)\,\Gamma\left(\frac43+n\right)\,n!^2\,(-256/c)^n}\tag1$$
$$y=3+2\sqrt3\,\pi\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(4\,n)!}{\Gamma\left(\frac23+n\right)\,\Gamma\left(\color{blue}{\frac13}+n\right)\,n!^2\,(-256/c)^n}\tag2$$
how do we show that $x,y$ in fact are *algebraic numbers*, being roots of the simple quartics,
$$cx^4+4x=3\tag3$$
$$c\Big(\tfrac{y}{y+1}\Big)^4+4\Big(\tfrac{y}{y+1}\Big)=3\tag4$$

Comment: $(3)$ is the consequence of Ramanujan's solution of trinomial equation in terms of power series in $c$. From $(1)$ it follows that $y/4=x+3cx'$, where $x'=\frac{dx}{dc}$. Differentiating $(2)$ gives $4(cx^3+1)x'+x^4=0$. Combining these equations one can easily show that $y=\frac{x}{1-x}$.